# grep - exclude certain domains from url search

Tags: string, url, grep

data_file.txt contains URLs, something like:

```
bunch of data http://good1.com/contact
lines of non-url data
bunch of data http://ok.ip.add.rss/page/1
lines of non-url data
bunch of data http://spammer.com/spammers/are/lame
lines of non-url data
bunch of data http://good2.com/page2
lines of non-url data
bunch of data http://good1.com/contact
```

Some are good URLs, some are spammer URLs.  I'm trying to find all the spammer URLs.

I can find the ***good*** URLs with:

```
grep -n -o -P 'http://(good1.com|ok.ip.add.rss|good2.com).{0,80}' data_file.txt
```

***I would like to reverse that***, finding anything that is *not* good.  I tried these variants:

```
grep -n -o -P 'http://*(^(good1.com|ok.ip.add.rss|good2.com)).{0,80}' data_file.txt
grep -n -o -P 'http://*^(good1.com|ok.ip.add.rss|good2.com).{0,80}' data_file.txt
grep -n -o -P 'http://*(^good1.com|^ok.ip.add.rss|^good2.com).{0,80}' data_file.txt
grep -n -o -P 'http://*(^good1.com\|^ok.ip.add.rss\|^good2.com).{0,80}' data_file.txt
grep -n -o -P 'http://*(^(good1.com|ok.ip.add.rss|good2.com)).{0,80}' data_file.txt
```

...but those didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `grep -v` to get the lines not matching the expression?

Comment: What does `-P` do? Why the `.{0,80}`? And the `-o` doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: `-P` its a Perl regular expression

Comment: Sorry about that sergioFC and ooga.  My data was originally misleading.  There is much non-URL data between the URLs.  -o helps to show only what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with a double grep:

```
grep -n -o -P "http://.*?[^/'\\\\)<]*" data_file.txt | grep -v "http://good1.com\|http://good2.com\|http://ok.ip.add.rss"
```

I had various characters--besides slashes--following the domains, hence the `[^/'\\\\)<]`